# Introduction of shared_ptr leads to a segmentation fault upon deserialization (with boost::serialization)

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, deserialization, shared-ptr

I have a class gamma, as shown below.

The load function throws a segmentation fault, when the make_nvp function tries to deserialize an existing xml file. The error comes when I use `std::shared_ptr<std::tuple<double,double,double>> val;`

If instead val is just `std::tuple<double,double,double> val;`

then everything seems to work fine (Of course, I change the getter and setter functions accordingly).

Now I went over a bunch of questions on stackoverflow and I googled and looked at the examples in boost documentation and I can't figure out, why the load function causes the program to terminate with a segmentation fault.

**Note:** Some old posts on the internet (and some older questions on stackoverflow) seem to imply that std::shared_ptr used to not work with boost serialization at that point in time. I don't think this is the case in 2017. Anyways, just to be sure, I tried replacing the std::shared_ptr with a boost::shared_ptr and the segmentation error was still there.

I don't understand/see why the error appears?

gamma.h

```
#pragma once
#include <map>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include <tuple>

namespace boost
{
    namespace serialization
    {
        template<typename Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, std::tuple<double, double, double> & t,
                    const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("t0",std::get<0>(t));
            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("t1",std::get<1>(t));
            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("t2",std::get<2>(t));
        }

    }
}

class Gamma
{
public:
    static void save(std::ostream& os);
    static void load(std::istream& is);

    std::shared_ptr<std::tuple<double, double, double>> getterX() const;
    void setterX(const std::tuple<double, double, double> &val);

private:

    std::shared_ptr<std::tuple<double,double,double>> val;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& arc, const unsigned int version)
    {
          arc & boost::serialization::make_nvp("val", val);
    }
};
```

and gamma.cpp

```
#include "gamma.h"
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>

Gamma &Gamma::instance()
{
    static Gamma obj;
    return obj;
}

std::shared_ptr<std::tuple<double, double, double>> Gamma::getterX() const
{
    return val;
}

void Gamma::setterX(const std::tuple<double, double,double> &v)
{
    if (nullptr == val) {
        m_touchDownCalibration = std::make_shared<std::tuple<double, double,double>>();
    }
    *val = v;
}

const char* TAG = "tag";

void Gamma::save(std::ostream& os)
{
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive arc(os);
    arc & boost::serialization::make_nvp(TAG,instance());
}

void Gamma::load(std::istream& is)
{
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive arc(is);
    arc & boost::serialization::make_nvp(TAG,instance());
}
```

Comment: You're code is incomplete and does not compile as is.

Comment: yes. I only added the class that caused the problem. This is part of a bigger project, where I arrive at this class after passing through a chain of other classes, starting from main. Let me see again, if I can add those classes here in a clean way.

Comment: @overseas, there was also a small mistake in the class name of the last two functions, load() and save(). I corrected that now.

The user sehe added just a main() for calling this class and it seems that he gets no segmentation fault there. Hmmm, curious! Probably the seg fault is caused by something else. Will check in a couple of hours.

Comment: Try to get a mcve (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we see what we can do. This code neither compiles (instance is missing) nor I can guess what problem you face, because if I correct the obvious errors and provide a simple `main` I can detect no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a mystery to me what a shared_ptr could actually add to a single tuple inside... a singleton. But anyways, I made your code self-contained and it works:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c58185fe0b2ff134)</kbd>**

I hope you can figure out which part you did differently/wrong:

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include <tuple>

namespace boost { namespace serialization {
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, std::tuple<double, double, double> & t, unsigned) {
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("t0", std::get<0>(t));
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("t1", std::get<1>(t));
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("t2", std::get<2>(t));
    }
} }

class CalibrationDataObject
{
public:
    static CalibrationDataObject &instance();
    static void save(std::ostream& os);
    static void load(std::istream& is);

    std::shared_ptr<std::tuple<double, double, double>> getterX() const;
    void setterX(const std::tuple<double, double, double> &val);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::tuple<double,double,double>> val;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& arc, unsigned)
    {
          arc & boost::serialization::make_nvp("val", val);
    }
};

//#include "CalibrationDataObject.h"
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>

CalibrationDataObject &CalibrationDataObject::instance() { static CalibrationDataObject obj; return obj; }

std::shared_ptr<std::tuple<double, double, double>> CalibrationDataObject::getterX() const {
    return val;
}

void CalibrationDataObject::setterX(const std::tuple<double, double,double> &v)
{
    if (val)
        *val = v;
    else 
        val = std::make_shared<std::tuple<double, double,double>>(v);
}

const char* TAG = "tag";

void CalibrationDataObject::save(std::ostream& os)
{
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive arc(os);
    arc & boost::serialization::make_nvp(TAG,instance());
}

void CalibrationDataObject::load(std::istream& is)
{
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive arc(is);
    arc & boost::serialization::make_nvp(TAG,instance());
}

#include <fstream>

int main() {
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("test.data");
        CalibrationDataObject::save(ofs);
    }
    {
        std::ifstream ifs("test.data");
        CalibrationDataObject::load(ifs);
    }
}
```

Printing the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="14">
<tag class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <val class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="1">
        <px class_id="-1"></px>
    </val>
</tag>
</boost_serialization>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for overlooking my copy/paste/edit mistake of forgetting to rename the class for the last two functions (load() and save()) from CalibrationDataObject to Gamma. :D

Give me a couple of hours, and I go over this again.

And Yes. You are right. Adding a shared_ptr seems to achieve nothing here (and the original code also did not use a shared_ptr at this location) but then somebody (not me) edited it (for some reason?!?) and upon testing, I noticed that it seemed to break the load function, which made me curious.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hmm, I see no error either. :/

Ok. This was in itself helpful. I accepted your answer.

Comment: @JoeyMallone perhaps you were loading an archive saved with the old version. The layout will not be compatible (you have to do [Class Versioning](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#versioning) if you want to load old archive formats)

Comment: We almost came to the same conclusion. Boost debug messages can be so cryptic. Only with experience can someone tell, what the error might be, 'cause the debug output seems completely unusable.